# Flipped card doesnt hold the back div on second animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a card that has the following animation:
When you click on "Edit" button:

- it moves to the center of the screen
- while moving it rotates 180deg (having a different back content - blank green)

After it gets to the center of the div and the rotation is done, the card expands to full screen (after which I redirect the user). **My problem is that after the second animation (actually when all animations are done) only then the back content is visible, in rest, when it's doing the rotate and translate, it's just the front content flipped visible (see JSFIDDLE down)** My code looks like:

Html:

```
<div class="cards-holder">
    <div class="card bg-light mb-3 item" style="display: none">
        <div class="front face">
        <div class="card-header kid-card-header">
            <div class="kid-card-header-name">
                <label>Child name:&nbsp;</label>
                <label>Kevin </label>
            </div>
            <div class="kid-card-header-delete-button">
                <i class="fa fa-trash-o deleteChild" aria-hidden="true" style="cursor: pointer" idOfChild="23"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="kid-card-content">
                <div class="kid-card-content-image">
                    //some image
                </div>
                <div class="kid-card-content-description">
                    <p class="card-text">
                        <label>Age: </label>
                        <label>2 years</label>
                    </p>
                    <p class="card-text">
                        <label>Gender: </label>
                        <label>Male</label>
                    </p>
                    <p class="card-text">
                        <label>Height: </label>
                        <label>50 cm</label>
                    </p>
                    <p class="card-text">
                        <label>Weight: </label>
                        <label>25 kg</label>
                    </p>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer kid-card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary editChildButton" ChildId="23">Edit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="back face">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.card {
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.face {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

    .face.back {
        display: block;
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
        background-color: #78C2AD;
    }
```

and JS:

```
$.fn.toggleZindex= function() {
    const $this = $(this);
    if($this.css("z-index")=="auto") {
        $this.css("z-index", "99999");
    }else {
        $this.css("z-index", "auto");
    }

    return this;
};

$.fn.animateRotate = function(angle, duration, easing, startingDegree, complete) {
    var args = $.speed(duration, easing, complete);
    var step = args.step;
    return this.each(function(i, e) {
        args.complete = $.proxy(args.complete, e);
        args.step = function(now) {
            $.style(e, 'transform', 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)');
            if (step) return step.apply(e, arguments);
        };

        $({ deg: startingDegree}).animate({deg: angle}, args);
    });
};

function getRotationDegrees(obj) {
    const matrix = obj.css("-webkit-transform") ||
        obj.css("-moz-transform")    ||
        obj.css("-ms-transform")     ||
        obj.css("-o-transform")      ||
        obj.css("transform");
    if(matrix !== 'none') {
        const values = matrix.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',');
        const a = values[0];
        const b = values[1];
        var angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(b, a) * (180/Math.PI));
    } else { var angle = 0; }
    return (angle < 0) ? angle + 360 : angle;
}

$('.editChildButton').on('click',
    function () {
        const idOfChild = $(this).attr('ChildId');
        const tc = $(window).height() / 2 - $('.item').height() / 2 - $(this.closest('.item')).offset().top;
        const lc = $(window).width() / 2 - $('.item').width() / 2 - $(this.closest('.item')).offset().left;

        $(this.closest('.item')).toggleZindex();

        const startingDegree = getRotationDegrees($(this.closest('.item')));

        $(this.closest('.item')).animateRotate(startingDegree == 0 ? 180 : 0, 2000, 'swing', startingDegree);

        $(this.closest('.item')).animate({
            left: lc,
            top: tc
        }, 2000, function () {
            $(this.closest('.item'))
                .css({
                    position: 'fixed', left: $(this.closest('.item')).offset().left, top:
                        $(this.closest('.item')).offset().top
                });
            $(this.closest('.item')).animate({
                left: 0,
                top: 0,
                width: '100vw',
                height: '100vh'
            }, 2000, function() {
                window.location =
                    "/Children/EditChild?childId=" + idOfChild;
            });
        });
    });
```

Demonstration of my problem [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/g4krgp8j/14/)

Basically, what I actually need is, from the moment the card rotated 180deg (from the first animation), only the blank green back is visible while doing the second animation. Also, at the end of all this, I need to redirect to another page, so I need to know when everything is done.

**I updated the JDFIDDLE to show the actual positioning of my cards.**

Comment: Can you create an MCVE in your question instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this issue (and save a lot of performance) by replacing your JS animation with a CSS animation.

See this for reference:
https://jsfiddle.net/g9wb4rwp/

```js
$('.editChildButton').on('click',  function () {       
    $('.flip-container').addClass('flip');       
});
```

```css
/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container {
 perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-container.flip .flipper {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.front, .back {
 width: 100%;
 height: 480px;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
 transition: 0.6s;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
 z-index: 2;
 /* for firefox 31 */
 transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
 transform: rotateY(180deg);
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="flip-container">
 <div class="flipper">
  <div class="front">
  <div class="card-header kid-card-header">
        <div class="kid-card-header-name">
          <label>Child name:&nbsp;</label>
          <label>Kevin</label>
        </div>
        <div class="kid-card-header-delete-button">
          <i class="fa fa-trash-o deleteChild" aria-hidden="true" style="cursor: pointer" idOfChild="23"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="kid-card-content">
          <div class="kid-card-content-image">
          </div>
          <div class="kid-card-content-description">
            <p class="card-text">
              <label>Age: </label>
              <label>2 years</label>
            </p>
            <p class="card-text">
              <label>Gender: </label>
              <label>Male</label>
            </p>
            <p class="card-text">
              <label>Height: </label>
              <label>50 cm</label>
            </p>
            <p class="card-text">
              <label>Weight: </label>
              <label>25 kg</label>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer kid-card-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary editChildButton" ChildId="23">Edit</button>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="back">
   Back
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Get end of css animation:

```
myselector.one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',  { 
    // code to execute after transition ends  
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see what you did on the example, but my card is inside some divs so it's only part of a bigger view (multiple cards) and with your implementation, the card doesn't rotate to full screen. Also, how can I redirect when the transition is done (when the card is full screen)?

Comment: For the first part, you can just edit the code from my fiddle so it fits your implementation (with the full screen). The css itself is pretty simple, so you should be able to adjust it to your needs easily. If you need some help please set up a fiddle showing where the issue is and I can take a look at it. For the transition done, you can bind transitionend to jquery .one method (one means it runs only once): myselector.one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',  { // code to execute after transition ends  }); I added it to the answer for easier copy

Comment: I tried to add width: 100vw and height: 100vh with top and left set as 0 but still, the back of the card is not positioned correctly. (it's on left bottom and continues beyond my screen. The webkitTransitionEnd is triggered when the animations starts for me... Add style="width:200px;height:45px" to your jsfiddle first level div and check

Comment: I updated my jsfiddle with the actual positioning of my cards to see why your answer is not helping me with the 'full screen' request

Comment: You just forgot to remove overflow hidden from your card after updating: https://jsfiddle.net/bLh7v6oq/ Is this what you meant?